# How to get input box (filterbox) values from ui-grid column header

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to get the input box values present in the ui-grid column header.

I'm trying to use my own filtering function which requires to get values from multiple input boxes in the column header.

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    {
        field: 'name', 
        displayName: 'Name', 
        headerCellTemplate: '<input type='text' &nbsp;disallow-spaces placeholder='Enter to Search'  ng-model='testCol' id='Enter to Search'>},
];
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add some code to show what you have and what you have tried to solve your problem?

Comment: $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [ 
{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', headerCellTemplate: <input type='text' &nbsp;disallow-spaces placeholder='Enter to Search'  ng-model='testCol' id='Enter to Search'>},
];

Comment: @GuranjanSingh Hi, I'm trying to get the value of the input box in the ui-grid

Answer (score 0):

You can give your custom filter to the `columnDef` like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
  {
    field: 'name', 
    displayName: 'Name', 
    headerCellTemplate: '<input type='text' &nbsp;disallow-spaces placeholder='Enter to Search'  ng-model='testCol' id='Enter to Search'>,
    filter: {
      type: uiGridConstants.filter.INPUT,
      condition: myCustomFilterFunction
  },
];
```

and your filtering function will look something like this:

```
function myCustomFilterFunction(term, value, row, column){
  //do something here
}
```

uiGrid will call the `myCustomFilterFunction` everytime the filter input changes. The parameter `term` refers is what you were looking for. It's the value present in the input box. Parameter `value` refers to the value of the column for the current row. Parameters `row` and `col` give you access to the current `rowEntity` and `column`.

`myCustomFilterFunction` should return a boolen. If the returned value for a row is true then the row is displayed otherwise not.